# How do I retrieve all user layouts using Ant Migration Tool?

Tags: page-layout, ant, standardlayout

When I go to the list of `User Page Layouts`, I see that there are three different User layouts available in my organization

```
Page Layout Name
User Layout
User Profile Layout
Community Member Layout
```

[image]

However, when I try to use package.xml with the following body,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>User-User Layout</members>
        <members>User-User Profile Layout</members>
        <members>User-Community Member Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <version>45</version>
</Package>
```

I receive an error saying

```
Retrieve warnings (2):
package.xml - Entity of type 'Layout' named 'User-Community Member Layout' cannot be found
package.xml - Entity of type 'Layout' named 'User-User Profile Layout' cannot be found
```

[image]

Usually a layout has the object developer name with hyphen symbol appended as a prefix to layout name when it is needed to retrieve it by Ant, at least the first layout is retrieved successfully, however, two other layouts are not.

Even if I change prefix to `User Profile` or to `Community Member`, it doesn't work, even when I try to use package.xml with the following body,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>User-User Layout</members>
        <members>User Profile-User Profile Layout</members>
        <members>Community Member-Community Member Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <version>45</version>
</Package>
```

and it returns the same error

```
Retrieve warnings (2):
package.xml - Entity of type 'Layout' named 'Community Member-Community Member Layout' cannot be found
package.xml - Entity of type 'Layout' named 'User Profile-User Profile Layout' cannot be found
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use `sf:listMetadata` target

```xml
<project name="Sandbox" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <target name="List Metadata Profiles">
        <sf:listMetadata username="${sf.sandbox.username}"
                         password="${sf.sandbox.password}${sf.sandbox.securityToken}"
                         serverurl="${sf.sandbox.serverurl}"
                         metadataType="Profile"
                         resultFilePath="profiles.txt" />
    </target>
</project>
```

to find out the names for the exotic page layouts. If this target is used, the `profiles.txt` can be examined to search the required names.

Actually it contains the required names.

```
CommunityMemberLayout-Community Member Layout
UserAlt-User Profile Layout
```

These names can now be used to retrieve the layouts metadata

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>User-User Layout</members>
        <members>UserAlt-User Profile Layout</members>
        <members>CommunityMemberLayout-Community Member Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <version>45</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error "Unknown type name 'User Profile Layout' specified in package.xml"

These kinds of errors are observed due to incorrect metadata types in the deployment process using the package.xml file.

An appropriate list of salesforce metadata types can be found using workbench.developerforce.com site under the Info : option 'Metadata Types and Components' will get total list.